# How to add dynamically, based on the result places, information to markers when clicked in Google Maps JavaScript Api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to customize my google map JS API code as to return the nearby pharmacies from the user location and put a box info when the user clicks one of the pharmacies. My code is working only for rendering pharmacies nearby, but does not pop up the info box when the user clicks on the marker.

```
let map;
        let service;
        let infowindow;
        function initialize() {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            //Map options
            var options = {
                center: userPosition,
                zoom: 15,
                // disableDefaultUI: true,
            }
            //New map
            map = new
                google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

            var request = {
                location: userPosition,
                radius: '2000',
                query: 'farmacie,spital',
            };

            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.textSearch(request, callback);;

            function addUserLocationMarker() {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map,
                    draggable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: userPosition,
                    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/grn-pushpin.png"
                });

                marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<h3>My Location ! </h3>"
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function () {
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            }
            addUserLocationMarker();
        }
        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var place = results[i];
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    // let markers = [];
        function createMarker(place) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map,
                position: place.geometry.location,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                place:AnimationEffect,
            });
            marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
                infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                infowindow.open(map);
            });
        }

function toggleBounce() {
            if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            } else {
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to open an [InfoWindow](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow) on a [Marker](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#marker) is [`.open(map, marker)`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.open) (assuming the reference to the marker is `marker`).  From the [documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.open):

> **open([map, anchor])**
> **Parameters:**
> **map:**  Map|StreetViewPanorama optional
> **anchor:**  MVCObject optional
> **Return Value:**  None
> Opens this InfoWindow on the given map. Optionally, an InfoWindow can be associated with an anchor. In the core API, the only anchor is the Marker class. However, an anchor can be any MVCObject that exposes a LatLng position property and optionally a Point anchorPoint property for calculating the pixelOffset (see InfoWindowOptions). The anchorPoint is the offset from the anchor's position to the tip of the InfoWindow.

(you can do it without including the `anchor`, but *only* if you set the position of the InfoWindow, using `.setPosition`)

You have it correct in the `addUserLocationMarker` function, but it is wrong it the `createMarker` function:

```
function createMarker(place) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        place:AnimationEffect,
    });
    marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map);  // <--------------------------
    });
}
```

should be:

```
function createMarker(place) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        place:AnimationEffect,
    });
    marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);  // <--------------------------
    });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zu4kjnhr/1/)

[image: screenshot of working map]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;
let service;
let infowindow;
let userPosition = {
  lat: 40.7127753,
  lng: -74.0059728
}

function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var options = {
    center: userPosition,
    zoom: 15,
  }
  //New map
  map = new
  google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

  var request = {
    location: userPosition,
    radius: '2000',
    query: 'pharmacy',
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);;

  function addUserLocationMarker() {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map,
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: userPosition,
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/grn-pushpin.png"
    });

    marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "<h3>Locatia mea ! </h3>"
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
  addUserLocationMarker();
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Place Searches</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=places&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```